# Why after an exception, do I have to do a Ctrl-C in the terminal to unlock the spring boot application, to continu to process the other requests

Tags: java, spring-boot, terminal

i have a Spring boot application running with java -jar myapps.jar
when an exception occured, the application doesn't process any other request (rest calls),
the process is bloqued, and i have to do a Ctrl-C in the terminal, then the process in unlocked and resume the execution of blocked calls that were received after the call that caused the exception !!?

Comment: Handle the exception so the thread doesn’t die.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen you think that a generic exception handler could resolve the prb ?

Comment: @JeffHolt i am on a Window Server VM

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem : I handeled expetions in my controllers by throwing a org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException object